# how to send the mail to the desired user from iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am sending mail from iphone application 
 i want that instead of this static reception user should enter in to field in mail and mail should be sent to them.

```
    - (void)onEmailResult
    {

   if ([[MFMailComposeViewController class] canSendMail]) {
     MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
     picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

     [picker setSubject:@"Game"];

     // Set up recipients
     NSArray * toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"husain_2000@yahoo.com"];
     [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];

     // Fill out the email body text
     NSString * emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My Score: %d/%d, My Time: %@", numberOfCorrectAnswer, [[[DataManager sharedInstance] questions] count], time];
     [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

     [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
     [picker release];
     }


     else {
     NSString *recipients = @"mailto:husain_2000@yahoo.com?&subject=Game";
     NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&body=My Score: %d/%d, My Time: %@", numberOfCorrectAnswer, [[[DataManager sharedInstance] questions] count], time];

     NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", recipients, body];
     email = [email stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:email]];
    }
   }
```

Comment: just enter their email ID in address field manually?

Comment: if i will enter the email id manullay then it will send to that in app or not

Comment: Ofcourse it will send, why don't you try ? And note that it won't work on simualtor, you need an actual device with a mail account set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The email should be configured in the iPhone.

Then Try this code

```
- (void)onEmailResult
    {

   if ([[MFMailComposeViewController class] canSendMail]) {
     MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
     picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

     [picker setSubject:@"Game"];

     // Leave recipients as blank


     // Fill out the email body text
     NSString * emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My Score: %d/%d, My Time: %@", numberOfCorrectAnswer, [[[DataManager sharedInstance] questions] count], time];
     [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

     [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
     [picker release];
     }



   }
```